# Annotation in OWL API

Tags: owl, owl-api

I am learning how to use OWL API, I found this API is not the same as the API I used before. I am trying to figure out some simple concepts.I can't understand "Annotation". I get these [from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Ontology_Language#OWL_abstract_syntax):

> The OWL abstract syntax presents an ontology as a sequence of
>   *annotations*, *axioms* and *facts*. Annotations carry machine and human
>   oriented meta-data.

If you are familiar with the owl, can you give me an example? What does "machine and human oriented meta-data" mean?
Thanks a lot.

---

Update:

---

Thanks for answering me. I also want to write a example:

```
<http://data.doremus.org/performance/4db95574-8497-3f30-ad1e-f6f65ed6c896>
    a                      mus:M42_Performed_Expression_Creation ;
    ecrm:P3_has_note       "Créée par Teodoro Anzellotti, son commanditaire, en novembre 1995 à Rotterdam" ;
    ecrm:P4_has_time-span  <http://data.doremus.org/performance/4db95574-8497-3f30-ad1e-f6f65ed6c896/time> ;
    ecrm:P9_consists_of    [ a                        mus:M28_Individual_Performance ;
                             ecrm:P14_carried_out_by  "Teodoro Anzellotti"
                           ] ;
    ecrm:P9_consists_of    [ a                        mus:M28_Individual_Performance ;
                             ecrm:P14_carried_out_by  "à Rotterdam"
                           ] ;
    efrbroo:R17_created    <http://data.doremus.org/expression/2fdd40f3-f67c-30a0-bb03-f27e69b9f07f> ;
    efrbroo:R19_created_a_realisation_of
            <http://data.doremus.org/work/907de583-5247-346a-9c19-e184823c9fd6> ;
    efrbroo:R25_performed  <http://data.doremus.org/expression/b4bb1588-dd83-3915-ab55-b8b70b0131b5> .
```

---

I think there is annotation in this example, the object of "ecrm:P9_consists_of" is not annotation. If I want to add annotation to ecrm:P3_has_not, how to do that?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest example of owl-annotation is a annotation assertion, e.g:

```
_:x rdfs:comment "this is a comment"@en
```

where predicate rdfs:comment - is a builtin annotation property, and there are 8 such builtin properties.
you can also provide your own annotation properties. 
you can also make annotation of annotations and build a tree of annotations.
The example of сomplex nested annotations (turtle):

```
[ a                      owl:Annotation ;
  rdfs:comment           "indi-comment" ;
  owl:annotatedProperty  rdfs:comment ;
  owl:annotatedSource    [ a                      owl:Axiom ;
                           rdfs:comment           "INDI-ANN" ;
                           owl:annotatedProperty  rdf:type ;
                           owl:annotatedSource    :Indi ;
                           owl:annotatedTarget    :SomeClass1
                         ] ;
  owl:annotatedTarget    "INDI-ANN"
] .
```

The same in functional syntax:

```
ClassAssertion(Annotation(Annotation(rdfs:comment "indi-comment"^^xsd:string) rdfs:comment "INDI-ANN"^^xsd:string) <#SomeClass1> <#Indi>)
```

Here we have class-assertion axiom, which binds named-individual ':Indi' with class ':SomeClass1'; this axiom is annotated with rdfs:comment="INDI-ANN", which, in its turns, has annotation rdfs:comment(annotation-property)="indi-comment"(annotation-value).

I think functional-syntax representation can be considered as 'human-oriented meta-data', while turtle as 'machine-oriented' one.

In general, annotation is a way to provide additional (and optional) information about owl-statements (owl-axioms). It could be a version, a link, some custom annotation-property, etc.

Remark: it is about OWL2 specification rather then about OWL-API. Any API which meets specification must provide the similar way to handle owl-annotations.

Comment: Thanks for answering. About "_:x rdfs:comment "this is a comment"@en" , "_:x" is subject and "rdfs:comment" is predicate, is it right? I also was wondering what is the difference between axiom and annotations? I can't separate them.

Comment: right. ":x" is a subject in the triple '_:x rdfs:comment "this is a comment"@en'; the last part '"this is a comment"@en' is an object, and also a string literal. owl:Axiom and owl:Annotation are just uri's from owl2 vocabulary. A root bulk annotation has (usually) a rdf:type=owl:Axiom, while a nested annotation has rdf:type=owl:Annotation. They are not directly related to the owl-axioms, rather are parts of RDF-serialization,

Comment: OK I got it. I have re-updated the answer, can you have a look at it? Excuse me for giving you so much trouble, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I should read the doc about OWL 2 carefully, thank you. @Sigrem

Comment: the statement '<http://...96> ecrm:P3_has_note "C...m"' looks like annotation-assertion.But the statement '_:x ecrm:P9_consists_of []' looks like an object property assertion rather then then annotation-property assertion, because the object can be anonymous individual, if it is owl-2.
Note: owl2 requires explicit declarations for every owl-entities. To make the first statement to be annotation you can add triple "ecrm:P3_has_note a owl:AnnotationProperty", and for second statement you can add "ecrm:P9_consists_of a owl:ObjectProperty" and "mus:M28_Individual_Performance a owl:Class".

Comment: I would have said that 'human oriented' means the content of a comment, when this comment is text only a human can understand; e.g., free text. 'machine oriented' refers to any annotations whose content is structured somehow - can be a URI, a code reference to some standard, a fragment of XML or other data that was not encoded in the ontology itself, or anything else of this sort. The serialization format must not matter, as the abstract syntax is abstracted from serialization syntaxes :-) pun intended